# How to Monitor Changes in a Directory on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, c, macos, filesystems

In the Windows API, when you monitor a directory, the callback provides what changed. How do I accomplish the same for Mac OS X?

I looked at the File System Events API and the Kernel Events API and it seems like they both watch a file descriptor and return what changes happened to that file descriptor. This is inconvenient because now I have to open watchers on the entire file structure and remember the previous names (in case of a rename).

Is there a better way (that doesn't involve a library)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FSEvents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH4-DontLinkElementID_11) watches a directory hierarchy (or multiple hierarchies), not a file descriptor.  So you only need one watcher.  But you will need to scan the directories to find out which files changed.  There is no better way (that doesn't involve a library).